# How to offer a C++ Windows software as a service

Tags: azure, virtualization, saas, citrix, vdi

We (ISV) are currently planning to offer our software on a rental/subscription basis as a service.
It's a native Windows (C++ / .NET) B2B application.
Our software needs access to the file system (drives) on the customers computer and it also needs access to the network (e.g. be able to find other computers in the network).

We want to offer our customers a service where they do not have to bother themselves with setup/updates and always work with the newest version of our software. So we need a single point of maintenance.

In the first phase we do not expect a lot of our customers (let's say 20) to change to this model, so it would not be a problem to have to set them up and manage them manually, but in the long run a solution that allows an automated set/sign up process would be required.

What I found most promising was Citrix XenDesktop/XenApp with VM hosted Apps and personal vDisks, but it seems that the Citrix solution is not able to get access to the network on the client PC (I tried it with the trial in the Azure Marketplace). Also it seems to be high priced.

What would be other possible ways to meet these requirements?

Comment: You can craft an equivalent of Windows Update service and all customers software could update itself periodically but you cannot really force immediate updates because you have to wait before your users finish their work, save their data and allow the update.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can make some significant architectural changes to eliminate the need to access the local filesystem and and eliminate the need to do local network browsing, I would recommend focusing on optimizing your local installation and update process. And skip the virtualization/service idea "for now".

You can still go to subscription model with a locally installed application. Just require your application to "phone home" to check its licensing/subscription status on startup.